# Xcode not creating .h file

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

I am using Xcode 6.0.1

I created a new project which automatically generated .h and .m files .

When I try to add a new Objective-C file, it is only creating .m file. .h file is not getting generated.
I tried all preferences, nowhere i found an option which says "Generate .h file".

Out of curiosity I checked Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates where only one folder exists.

/Users/rajeshreddy/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates
Rajeshs-MacBook-Pro:Templates rajeshreddy$ ls
File Templates cocos2d v3.x
Rajeshs-MacBook-Pro:Templates rajeshreddy$

Is there any setting which I can enable to generate .h file?

Answer (score 5):

You need to create a new CocoaTouch *class*, like this:

[image: Create a new cocoa touch class]

And that should give you both a .m and a .h file.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. What is the difference between COCOA-TOUCH class and Objective-c class. Earlier i used to create Objective-c class which generated .h and .m files

Comment: Cocoa Touch means that it'll be linking with UIKit (i.e. iOS), so there will likely be a "`#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>`" line at the top of the .h file.