# Why is NSFontManager.availableMembers(ofFontFamily:) crashing in Xcode 8 GM?

Tags: xcode, macos, crash, xcode8, nsfontmanager

I wrote this in Xcode 8 Beta 6 (8S201h):

```swift
guard let faceMembers = NSFontManager.shared().availableMembers(ofFontFamily: familyName ?? fontName) else { return nil }
```

And it worked just fine. Now that I've upgraded to <s>Xcode 8 GM Seed (8A218a)</s> Xcode 8 (8A218a), it crashes (`EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`).

Using the debugger to narrow it down, I found that something in `NSFontManager.availableMembers(ofFontFamily:)` really hates this, since it crashes no matter what I put in there, even with common (definitely installed!) fonts like Helvetica Neue.

```
(lldb) po NSFontManager.shared()
<NSFontManager: 0x6100000a24c0>

(lldb) po familyName
▿ Optional<String>
  - some : "Helvetica Neue"


(lldb) po fontName
"HelveticaNeue"


(lldb) po NSFontManager.shared().availableMembers(ofFontFamily: familyName ?? fontName)
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.
(lldb) po NSFontManager.shared().availableMembers(ofFontFamily: familyName!)
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.
(lldb) po NSFontManager.shared().availableMembers(ofFontFamily: "Not a real font?!")
nil
```

So when I pass it a valid font family name, it crashes... but when I pass it a fake one, it returns `nil`.

**Is this a problem I can solve, or just an issue with <s>Xcode 8 GM Seed</s> Xcode 8 which will be solved in an SDK update?**

---

After looking through the crash log, I saw this suspiciousness:

```
Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libswiftFoundation.dylib        0x0000000107cbb249 _TZFE10FoundationSa26_forceBridgeFromObjectiveCfTCSo7NSArray6resultRGSqGSax___T_ + 153
1   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001079031f3 swift_dynamicCast + 1635
2   libswiftCore.dylib              0x000000010790448b _dynamicCastFromExistential(swift::OpaqueValue*, swift::OpaqueValue*, swift::TargetExistentialTypeMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*, swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*, swift::DynamicCastFlags) + 91
3   libswiftCore.dylib              0x0000000107903919 swift_dynamicCast + 3465
4   libswiftFoundation.dylib        0x0000000107d6a348 _TPA__TFFs15_arrayForceCastu0_rFGSax_GSaq__U_FQ_Q0_ + 56
5   libswiftFoundation.dylib        0x0000000107cbbc45 _TFEsPs10Collection3mapurfzFzWx8Iterator7Element_qd__GSaqd___ + 885
6   libswiftFoundation.dylib        0x0000000107cbb4c3 _TFs15_arrayForceCastu0_rFGSax_GSaq__ + 227
7   libswiftFoundation.dylib        0x0000000107cbb7a5 _TZFE10FoundationSa36_unconditionallyBridgeFromObjectiveCfGSqCSo7NSArray_GSax_ + 197
```

So it seems like it's crashing within Swift-Foundation, in some function called `_forceBridgeFromObjectiveC`... not sure if that helps anyone but it does confirm it's within the SDK/runtime.

Comment: I submitted this as Apple Bug `28209297`

Comment: My submitted Apple Bug was marked as a duplicate of `28195947`, which is still open.

Comment: Did you submit a radar for this? Apple bug management is a complete nightmare and we will never know the outcome. If not I will submit one

Comment: @livingstonef I submitted via Apple Radar, not OpenRadar, if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

The only way that I could figure out how to work around this in the meantime was to create a static method in an objective-c class. I then imported the header into my bridging header and called the static method from Swift 3, where it worked fine.

Hope this helps you get through these difficult times!

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface WorkAround : NSObject

+ (NSArray *)typefacesForFontFamily:(NSString *)family;

@end


#import "WorkAround.h"

@implementation WorkAround

/// Returns an array of arrays, or nil, that contain information about
/// each typeface found for the specified font family.
+ (NSArray *)typefacesForFontFamily:(nonnull NSString *)family {
  NSFontManager *fontManager = [NSFontManager sharedFontManager];
  return [fontManager availableMembersOfFontFamily:family];
}
@end
```

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, but this is still crashing for me :c

Answer (score 1):

Joseph E.'s answer is a good starting point. However to get it to work in Swift 3, Xcode 8 (8A218a) I had to approach differently...

1. Subclass NSFontManager (in Objective C), and create the bridging header if you don't already have one. 
   [image]
   [image]

Make sure to change the language to (Objective C). Its important that you do it this way, as it appears [you cannot directly create an objective c m files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26085220/xcode-not-creating-h-file), even though there is an option to do so.

2. Implementation

FontManager.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface FontManager : NSFontManager
    NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

    + (NSArray *)typefacesForFontFamily:(NSString *)family;


    NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
@end
```

FontManager.m

```
#import "FontManager.h"

@implementation FontManager
    NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

    + (NSArray *)typefacesForFontFamily:(nonnull NSString *)family {
        NSFontManager *fontManager = [self sharedFontManager];
        return [fontManager availableMembersOfFontFamily:family];
    }

    NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
@end
```

bridging-header.h

```
//
//  Use this file to import your target's public headers that you would like to expose to Swift.
//

#import "FontManager.h"
```

3. Usage in your Swift 3 project

   ```
   if let fontMembers = FontManager.typefaces(forFontFamily: "Arial") as? [[Any]]  { }
   ```

Comment: How is this different...? Sorry; I just can't tell.